# Ionic 3 Http request não adiciona header Authorization

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3

Olá, estou com sério problema ao fazer um HTTP REQUEST POST quando preciso adicionar um Header customizado. Minha API Backend, tem algumas rotas bloqueadas e requer autenticação via Token, preciso passa-lo no meu Header, no entanto não tem jeito disto funcionar.

Já tentei inúmeras alternativas, desde criar um interceptor para adicionar no Request meu Token Authorization, usei o proxy API (pensei que poderia ter alguma relação com CORS) e mudei várias vezes meu método de request usando dezenas de exemplos, mas nada ainda. :-|

Bem, agora meu código está assim:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login-home',
  templateUrl: 'login-home.html',
})
export class LoginHomePage {

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  toLogin(){
    var data = {
      user: 'lolo',
      password: 'lololo'
    };

    let url = 'https://lolololo.ngrok.io/auth/v1';

    this.httpClient.post(url, data)
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('AUTH', result.data.token);
        console.log(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  toTest(){

    let data = {};
    let url = 'https://lolololo.ngrok.io/upload/picture';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('AUTH')
    });

    this.httpClient.post(url, data, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log('sucesso ao salvar');
        console.log(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

O que tenho notado é que o IONIC parece fazer dois requests, o primeiro ele faz com o metodo OPTIONS e depois ele faz o REQUEST esperado, veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha API NodeJS está rodando com CORS devidamente configurada, habilitei todos os HEADERS, METHODS e Origin, para este teste, está tudo com *. A API está rodando via ngrok, uso a url uso no meu REQUEST do IONIC.

Alguém sabe me explicar o que pode estar ocorrendo e alguma alternativa para resolver o caso? E porquê o angular/ionic faz estes dois requests?

Answer (score 1):

As duas requisições é o comportamento padrão dos navegadores ao se utilizar CORS. O navegador faz automaticamente uma primeira requisição 
usando o método OPTIONS para determinar se a requisição é segura para ser enviada, isso é chamado de "Preflighted requests". Isso é feito pois 
requisições Cross-site podem ter implicações nos dados do usuário.

poderia incluir na pergunta o conteúdo da aba Response para as duas requisições?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Thiago! No fim consegui descobrir que o método está correto, parei para analisar a fundo minha API e descobri que meu auth estava sendo chamado em qualquer requisição. Mudei minha chamada para ocorrer apenas quando bater no verbo esperado. Era tão bobo o problema que fiquei horas revisando e recriando. :(